# List<string> emailAddress how to replace value in a particular string

Tags: c#

I have the following method

```
/// <summary>
    /// Replaces SemiColons with commas because SMTP client does not accept semi colons
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="emailAddresses"></param>
    public static List<string> ReplaceSemiColon(List<string> emailAddresses) // Note only one string in the list...
    {         
        foreach (string email in emailAddresses)
        {
            email.Replace(";", ",");
        }

        //emailAddresses.Select(x => x.Replace(";", ","));  // Not working either


        return emailAddresses;
    }
```

However the email string is not replacing the ";" with the ",".   What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should try setting it back to itself `email = email.Replace(";", ",");`

Answer (score 4):

[`String.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace.aspx) method returns *new* string. It doesn't change existing one.

> **Returns a new string** in which all occurrences of a specified Unicode
>   character or String in the current string are replaced with another
>   specified Unicode character or String.

As Habib [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19053047/liststring-emailaddress-how-to-replace-value-in-a-particular-string#comment28158654_19053095), using `foreach` with the current list gets a *foreach iteration variable* error. It is a read-only iteration. Create a new list and then add replaced values to it instead.

Also you can use for loop for modifying existing list which keyboardP explained on [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19053105/447156).

```
List<string> newemailAddresses = new List<string>();
foreach (string email in emailAddresses)
{         
     newemailAddresses.Add(email.Replace(";", ","));
}
return newemailAddresses;
```

Be aware since strings are *[immutable types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object)*, you can't change them. Even if you think you change them, you actually create new strings object.

Comment: Soner, you can't modify iteration variable in foreach `Cannot assign to 'email' because it is a 'foreach iteration variable'`

Comment: @Habib Arrrhghhhh! Fool me `:)` Updated. I think it is ok now.

Comment: it looks good, but you can use a simple `for` loop and modify an existing list instead of creating a new one

Comment: @Habib You are right. I put a reference to [keyboardP's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19053105/447156) which is a nice example how it can be done with `for` loop.

Answer (score 4):

As others have already mentioned that strings are [immutable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) *(`string.Replace` would return a new string, it will not modify the existing one)* and you can't modify the list inside a `foreach` loop. You can either use a `for` loop to modify an existing list or use LINQ to create a new list and assign it back to existing one. Like:

```
emailAddresses = emailAddresses.Select(r => r.Replace(";", ",")).ToList();
```

Remember to include using `System.Linq;`

Comment: Here is what I went with ----

Answer (score 3):

Strings are immutable so another string is returned. Try

```
for(int i = 0; i < emailAddress.Count; i++)
{
   emailAddress[i] = emailAddress[i].Replace(";", ",");
}
```

A foreach loop would not compile here because you're trying to change the iteration variable. You'd run into [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7838079/why-cant-we-assign-a-foreach-iteration-variable-whereas-we-can-completely-modi).

Comment: `+1` for not falling into a trap with `foreach` like me `:)`

Answer (score 0):

You should use somthing like:
var tmpList = new List();
add each modified email address to the tmplist
and when you are done, return the TmpList.
In .NET strings are inmutable, that's why your code doesnt work.