# Passing DataGridViewRow as referance

Tags: c#, for-loop, datagridview, foreach, iteration

I want to pass `DataGridviewRow` as a `ref` where i am assigning some value to its cells but i am unable to do this

```
foreach(DataGridViewRow dgr in dgvMarksEntryByClassWise.Rows)
{
   RowValueSet(ref dgr);
}
```

Here it is giving Compile time Error because dgr is an `foreach iteration variable`
Also i tried to do it with `for loop`

```
for (int i = 0; i < dgvMarksEntryByClassWise.Rows.Count; i++)
{
  RowValueSet(ref dgvMarksEntryByClassWise.Rows[i]);
}
```

But here also it is giving Compile time error:
 `A property,indexer or dynamic member acces cannot passed as an out reference`

I referd this question asked on above errors but did't Found any appropriate solution of my problem

- [foreach iteration variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7838079/2445111)
- [A property,indexer or dynamic member acces cannot passed as an out reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4518956/2445111)

Please Suggest me how to Do this

### Update Code

```
void RowValueSet(ref DataGridViewRow dgr)
{
dgr.Cells["StudentZero"].Value = ss.Where(w => w.MarksheetMarks == "0").Count();
if (ss.Count() != 0)
dgr.Cells["StudentISEmpty"].Value = Convert.ToInt16(lblTotlatStudent1.Text) - ss.Count();
else
dgr.Cells["StudentISEmpty"].Value = 0;
dgr.Cells["StudentEntry"].Value = ss.Count();
}
```

Comment: can you show the code of `RowValueSet`?

Comment: @Damith i had updated my codd

Comment: There's no reason RowValueSet needs the row passed by ref. Just pass it in, your code should work fine.

Comment: Just remove `ref` from your `RowValueSet` method and see if it works, I can't see any reason to pass by reference. `DataGridViewRow` is already a reference type.

Comment: if I remove ref than how changes made to a row reflect the row of datagridview row. this is not possible @DaveShaw

Comment: Have you tried it? Also, see this article by Jon Skeet on the topic: http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html

Comment: yes I tried it @DaveShaw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cannot assign an iterated, enumerated item using a "foreach" or even a "for".
i got around that once, using that piece of code :

```
List<DataGridViewRow> lstDgr = new List<DataGridViewRow>();
foreach(DataGridViewRow dgr in dgvMarksEntryByClassWise.Rows)
{
   DataGridViewRow dgrTemp = dgr;
   RowValueSet(ref dgrTemp);
   lstDgr.Add(dgrTemp);
}  
dgvMarksEntryByClassWise.Rows.Clear();
dgvMarksEntryByClassWise.Rows.AddRange(lstDgr); //Not sure about the AddRange, try the Add method instead
```

Hope this helps

Comment: and btw, i wouldn't use a "Ref", instead i would pass a DataGridViewRow object in return to simply have : lstDgr.Add(RowValueSet(dgr));

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the comments above, you do not need to pass `DataGridViewRow` by reference.  Remove `ref` from the parameter.

```
void RowValueSet(DataGridViewRow dgr)
{
    dgr.Cells["StudentZero"].Value = ss.Where(w => w.MarksheetMarks == "0").Count();
    if (ss.Count() != 0)
        dgr.Cells["StudentISEmpty"].Value = Convert.ToInt16(lblTotlatStudent1.Text) - ss.Count();
    else
        dgr.Cells["StudentISEmpty"].Value = 0;
    dgr.Cells["StudentEntry"].Value = ss.Count();
}
```

If the values in the grid do not appear to be updating, it's for another reason.  Do you re-bind the grid when you need to refresh the display?

Answer (score 1):

How about this ?

```
for (int i = 0; i < dgvMarksEntryByClassWise.Rows.Count; i++)
{
   var myRow = dgvMarksEntryByClassWise.Rows[i];
   RowValueSet(ref myRow);
}
```

Comment: sorry @Selman22 I pass it but still when i'm assigning value to cells of rows it is not assingning it to Datagridviewcells

Comment: it passed the row but value is not assigned to datagridview cell

Comment: then maybe the problem is in your RowValueSet method? are you sure it's correct?

Comment: i am sure there in no problem with rowvalueset

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comments about not passing the row using ref. It is a reference type. You generally only use that keyword with value types (such as int, etc).

I've had problems with the DataGridView not updating after changing cell values and often have needed to call dataGridView1.Invalidate(); It depends how things are hooked up. If you use data-binding with a class that inherits from INotifyPropertyChanged then it always seems to work, but if you just change cell values I have noticed the odd time that it would not update.

Here is an example that works. Create a new app, add an empty DataGridView onto the form and replace the code with the following. This proves that you do not need to use ref.

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn() { Name = "Column1" });
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn() { Name = "Column2" });
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn() { Name = "Column3" });
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn() { Name = "Column4" });

            for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
            }

            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                RowValueSet(row);
            }
        }

        private void RowValueSet(DataGridViewRow row)
        {
            row.Cells["Column1"].Value = "1";
            row.Cells["Column2"].Value = "2";
            row.Cells["Column3"].Value = "3";
            row.Cells["Column4"].Value = "4";
        }
    }
```

I imagine that your problem lies elsewhere