# Why struct properties cannot be changed if they are in a list?

Tags: c#, list, loops, compiler-errors, value-type

Please consider the following code:

```
public class Program {

    public struct A 
    {
        public int Prop {get;set;}
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        var obj = new A();
        obj.Prop = 10;

        var list = new List<A>(){obj};
        foreach(var l in list) {
            l.Prop = 20; //here I'm getting compile time error "Cannot modify members of 'l' because it is a 'foreach iteration variable'"
        }
    }
}
```

So my question is: why struct properties cannot be assigned while iterating over a list of structs?
Please note that even when iterating with simple for like this:

```
for (int i=0; i<list.Count(); ++i)
    list[i].Prop  = 20;
```

I'm still getting compile time error...

Comment: About that for loop. You'll need to create a copy of a struct. See: [Changing the value of an element in a list of structs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51526/changing-the-value-of-an-element-in-a-list-of-structs)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify collection over which you are iterating with `foreach`.

Instead you should use `for` loop, which allows that:

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.Length; i++)
{
  list[i].Prop = 200;
}
```

You can refer to this question: [Why can't we assign a foreach iteration variable, whereas we can completely modify it with an accessor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7838079/why-cant-we-assign-a-foreach-iteration-variable-whereas-we-can-completely-modi)

Comment: Please checkout an update, I'm still not able to make changes to properties even within **for** loop

Comment: Sorry, there's a different issue at play here. Collection is not modified anywhere in the code. Your code will only compile if `list` is an array.